# Analyze process workflow in order to give some recommendations to user

Tags: java, oop, analytics

Let's imagine that

- We have some interface where a user inputs some parameters (dozens of parameters)
- Then the user clicks "process" and parameters is sent to backend
- In the backend we do some difficult calculations which are based on received parameters
- If our calculations were successfully finished and we got a sensible result we just show It to user
- But calculations could have failed. And we want to give to user some information about how he could change an input in order to get valid result. And yes, the parameters can be strongly coupled with each other (dependent).

So the questions are:

1. How is this process called? I mean the process of analysis the workflow along all the calculations?
2. Are there some best practices to implement such analysis? Maybe some papers/articles about It?
3. Could you advise some approaches to implement It and plug in this code in existing code in OOP stype, maybe some patterns?

Comment: This question is too broad - how can anyone suggests how your data should be modelled without knowing what it is and how they relate?

Comment: I'm not looking for exact solution. I'm rather trying to know how is this called and looking for some papers about the analysis of complex processes